# Nodejs and Expressjs print session out on site

Tags: node.js, express

Hello i am trying to do a simple log in system  without(password) in nodejs and expressjs, using sessions. My problem is that when I try to print the log in name on to the next page it dosent come out.

login html:

```
<form method="post">
<label for="">UserName:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username" >
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

main.html:

```
<h3> Welcome: <%= user %> </h3>
```

index.js:

```
 var express = require('express');
 var jokes = require('../model/jokes');
 var session = require("express-session") 
 var router = express.Router();


 /* GET home page. */

 router.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.render('main', { title: 'Express', user: session.loggedin });

 })

 router.get('/login',function(req,res){
 res.render('login');
 })

 router.get('/joke', function(req,res){
 res.render('randomJoke',{ jokesObj : jokes.getRandomJoke()});
 })

 router.get('/allJokes', function(req,res){

 res.render('Jokes',{ jokesObj1: jokes.allJokes});

 })

 router.get('/addNewJoke', function(req,res){
 res.render('addJokes');
 })

router.post('/storeJoke', function(req,res){
var funJoke = req.body;
var jsonJoke = JSON.stringify(funJoke);
jokes.addJoke(jsonJoke);
res.redirect('/addNewJoke');
})


module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var session = require("express-session");


var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();



app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');




// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({secret:'secret_3162735',saveUninitialized:true,          resave: true}));



 app.use('/', routes);
 app.use('/users', users);


 app.use(function (req,res,next) {
 var usernameLogged = req.session.loggedin;
 var inputName = req.body.username;


 if(usernameLogged){

 return next();.
 }else if(inputName){
 usernameLogged = inputName;
 session.userName = req.body.username;
 return res.redirect("/");

 }else{
 req.url = "/login";
 return next();
 }
 });



 // error handlers

 // catch 404 and forward to error handler
 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 var err = new Error('Not Found');
 err.status = 404;
 next(err);
 });






// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error', {
message: err.message,
error: err
});
});
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error', {
message: err.message,
error: {}
});
});


module.exports = app;
```

So in main.html i cant se the user, i tried to print the session(usernameLogged) out in my main.html does not work.

Comment: Where did you try to log the session? On the front or the back?

Comment: front-end. in main.html

Comment: On your router, before rendering the response,  did you get the correct user name?  Session.loggedin has the correct value?

Comment: Before `res.render` type `console.log(Session.loggedin)` to be sure that you render your template with something in `user`

Comment: I just did and it gives me undefined.

Comment: I am new to this i can't really se what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: OK and if you replace `Session.loggedin ` by `foo` do you get `foo` when the template is rendered?

Comment: yes and I get foo when I replace session.loggedin with 'foo'.

Comment: Have you correctly setup express-session? can you edit your answer to include all of `app.js?`

Comment: OK the problem just come from the fact that your `req` object do not have any property named `session` so it return `undefined`... You get something with `req..body.username` or nothing ?

Comment: well when i print it out in console it gives me the name i have typed in.

Comment: why is everyone here (question and answers) using `session` instead of `req.session`? `session` is just an object shared between all requests....

Comment: Really good spot, I'll edit my answer (how could I miss that!?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see it looks like your using middleware in a way it's not really supposed to be used. Middleware in Express is normally used to do an action for every (or a sub-section) of requests e.g logging, setting custom headers and so on, you can read more about Express-middleware from the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html).

You need to have a route to respond to POST requests (which your login form should send):

Firstly, your `login` template needs to send the form input to `/login` like so:

```
<form method="post" action="/login">
  <label for="">UserName:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username" >
  <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

To display the form you have a route like so to simply render the login template:

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res) {  
  // Show the login form
  res.render('login');
})
```

Finally, you should have a route to accept the user-input from the form. As the form sends a POST request, you need to use `router.post`:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {

  if (req.session.loggedin) {
    // User is already logged in, send them to the main page 
    return res.redirect('/')
  } 

  else if (req.body.username) {
    // User is not logged in, set the username for the user's session
    req.session.userName = req.body.username;
    // Then redirect to the main page
    return res.redirect('/')    
  } 

  else {
    // No username was entered
    res.send('Please enter a username')
  }
})
```

And finally,

You then should be safe to delete your middleware (the `app.use` section) of your app.js file.

Edit:

A user correctly spotted that questions (and answers) were using `session` rather than using `req.session` - Session refers to the  express-session module, whereas `req.session` refers to the user's session.

So your `'/'` route should look like this:

```
res.render('main', { title: 'Express', user: req.session.loggedin });
```

If you want to show if the user is logged in or not.

Or you can do the following to show the current user's username.

```
res.render('main', { title: 'Express', user: req.session.userName });
```

Comment: when doint this it dosent go on to the next site, it just stays in log in page it never goes on to main.html ?

Comment: See my re-factored code in my edited answer above, see if that helps. Basically, the code checks to see if the user is logged-in, if they are - continue to the next route. If they aren't logged in then it sets `session.userName` to what they entered in the form. If they aren't logged in, or they haven't sent a username in the request, continue to the next route.

Comment: i just copy and pasted your code, it just stays in log in page it dosent go on, to my main.html.

Comment: it goes on if I put app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

Comment: the 2 lines above my custom middleware.

Comment: but I still cant see the name that was the original problem.

Comment: Yes, but then your middleware won't run that way. It is _super_ hard to tell what is going on without all your code. Can you include all routes associated with logging in (GET & POST routes) e.g `router.get('/login', ...)` in your question?

Comment: if you want to see more of my code, please let me know.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. If you've found it to fix the problem can you mark it as a solution?

Comment: yes I will, but I am not sure if it fixed the problem.

Comment: sorry this dosent work, I will try fix it with my middleware app.use. If you have any ideas please let me know.

Comment: It _should_ work, I can make a brand-new express app and copy and paste the code and it will work. The last thing I can suggest is shouldn't your main.html file (and any other views) be named main.ejs (if your using EJS to render views? Finally, I'd suggest you look at the express documentation [guides](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html), they can be really useful if you are new to Express.

Comment: Then maybe my mistake is somewhere else:S                                       They are named ejs my mistake.

Comment: See [here](https://gist.github.com/aboxshall/ede82c98767ba02b2b45) for the exact code used to reproduce your issue. It works as intended - user visits the login page`'/login'`, enters a username and then gets redirected to `'/'`, which shows their username. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much. I will take a look :) it works fine with your code now but I want it to make it happen with app.use middleware, but maybe your code can help me.

Comment: I think you'll find it hard, doing what you want (form your original question) will end up with a redirect loop. There is probably some hack to get it to work, but you'll end up with really ugly code. If you explain what you want (and why you want to use middleware) that might be better, e.g "User goes to login page then X happens, I want the middleware to do Y"

Comment: Well its was just try out really, no special reason to use the middleware. My original quisten was to get the name printed out in the front end. But I fixed the problem with 2 lines app.use('/', routes); app.use('/users', users);  they can now be under my custom middleware without being stuck in login page.

Comment: I have just seen your edit, but completed this 2 days ago, and also like you i used req.session.userName, but stile with middleware so it works nice now :) Thank you for your help Ashley.